# Date AND Time picker control for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'd like to have a date AND time picker for my Silverlight application.

AFAIK there are date and time controls in the SDK and the toolkit but they pick either a date OR a time. I'd like to have the same kind of control that's available in WinForms where I can pick a date AND time at the same time.

Cheer.

Answer (score 2):

I've not used it myself, but [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ebsldatetimepicker) seems to do what you're looking for.

Comment: It's basically the same implementation of what I've done. I'm not going to use it as it's for a commercial application and the license doesn't quite allow that.

Thanks for the pointer.